# Would like to run a query that is using a field in a table for it's criteria (would like to loop)

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am new and have very basic knowledge of programming.

So, I have a table that contains fields that is written in the same way as you would write a criteria for a field in queries (ex: the field would contain `"1234 Or 1242"` or some date range: `"Between #06/23/2019# and #06/25/2019#"`). I would like to run a loop that looks at each line of this table and run queries that are referencing these fields

I've figured out the loop but for the life of me I can't figure out how to run the query with the string in the field of the referenced table as a criteria. So I left it blank.

```vb
Sub testPromo_Click()

Dim strSQL As String
Dim strDEPTCriteria As String
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

strSQL = "PromoTable"
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

With rs
    If Not .BOF And Not .EOF Then
    .MoveFirst
        While (Not .EOF)

            DoCmd.OpenQuery "SelectedDepts"

            .MoveNext
        Wend
    End If
    .Close
End With

ExitSub:
    Set rs = Nothing
    Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Comment: Your criteria in table does not include field that filter must be applied to and the logical operator that should be used, e.g. `fieldname IN(1234, 1242)`. What is purpose of looping through recordset when code opens same query object? Really need to open form or report instead of query. But again, the looping makes no sense.